# Paso de parámetros a una subrutina en ensamblador

Tags: funciones, ensamblador, x86, parametros

El código es en ensamblador x86/64. Quiero pasar dos valores como parámetros a una subrutina pero tengo una duda: Los parámetros que van antes del call de una subrutina son los que se almacenan en la pila y luego les asigna un valor con mov no (es como he visto que están en otros ejemplos)?. En el código de abajo rdi es un parámetro de la subrutina CalcularPos y lo que pretende la función es hacer unos cálculos (división y suma y módulo y suma) y pasar estos resultados como parámetros a otra subrutina. Ahora bien, algo se me escapa porque no me pasa bien los parámetros a esta función. No sé de que depende para que pase bien los parámetros a una subrutina, yo pensaba que con almacenar en la pila los valores que quieres pasar y justo antes del call hacer un mov para asignarles un valor era suficiente pero algo no entendí porque no me funciona. Mi lógica no debe estar bien porque si quieres utilizar otros registros para otras cosas en la subrutina y no los quieres pasar como parámetro a una subrutina no sería posible, ya que si están almacenados en la pila y se les ha asignado algún valor ya serían parámetros a la función. ¿Dónde está el límite de cuando es parámetro a una subrutina que está dentro otra y cuando forma parte de la subrutina que la contiene, o sea, que tien que pasar para que sea parámetro y que tiene que pasar para que no? ¿Alguién puede ayudarme a entender mejor estos conceptos de paso de parámetros y decirme como tendría que poner el código para que haga lo que yo quiero y funcione? Muchas gracias por adelantado, saludos.

CalcularPos:

```
push rbp
mov  rbp, rsp

push rdx  
push rax    
push rdi

    mov rdx, 0           
    mov rax, rdi        
    mov rdi, 18
    div rdi              
    add rax, 12           

    add rdx, 11         

    call animarXY

pop rdi 
pop rax     
pop rdx

mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

La operación `push` **copia** un valor a la pila tal cual. No tiene mas. No enlaza, ni crea referencias, ni nada *mágico*. Realiza una copia, por lo que ambos elementos (el original y el copiado) son totalmente independientes. Las modificaciones en uno no afectan para nada al otro.

Por lo tanto, si haces un `push` y luego modificas el valor, dichos cambios **no se trasladan a la pila**.

Simplemente, realiza tus operaciones **antes** de hacer `push`:

```
mov rdx, 0
mov rax, rdi
mov rdi, 18
div rdi
add rax, 12
add rdx, 11

push rdx
push rax
push rdi

call animarXY
```

Comment: He entendido lo del push, pero si tengo una subrutina, que se llama CalcularPos, donde está todo el código con las operaciones y dentro de esta llamo a otra subrutina 'call animarXY' cómo le paso como parámetros rax y rdx?. En el código que me has mostrado no me funciona, aunque si puede ser ponme toda la subrutina como sería porque si pones registros dentro de una subrutina tienes que poner el push pop porque sino los pones serían los valores devueltos por la subrutina y yo pensaba que el push se ponía al principio de la subrutina después del "mov rbp, rsp".

Comment: Los *parametros* en ensamblador **no existen**. La CPU opera con registros. Los registros se pueden *cargar* con datos leídos en posiciones de memoria. Lo que tú llamas *paso de parámetros* es una simple **convención** para indicar en donde buscará el código los datos necesarios. Puedes pasar parámetros sin usar la pila. Y la pila es una **ayuda**. Para usarla, haces `push` para *meter* cosas y `pop` para *sacarlas*. El orden en el que haces las operaciones es **importante**: es una LIFO. Puedes usar la *conveción de paso de parámetros* que quieras, incluso mezcla de registros y pila.

Comment: Hay multitud de tutoriales en Internet sobre estos conceptos; deberías hacer varias pruebas hasta que los comprendas. Dentro de un rato borraré mi respuesta.

Comment: Ya me ha funcionado, se ve que los seis primeros parámetros que se pasan en los registros son RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9 y he utilizado los dos primeros como parámetros y me ha funcionado.

Comment: Por favor, quita la marca de *aceptada* de la respuesta. Así no puedo eliminarla.